# Hi everybody, I'm not seeing the X,Y and Z selection in the upper left of the edit window when using the Spin tool

Tags: interface

I have Blender 2.8 installed on both of my computers, and I've tried every simple spin tool tutorial on Youtube, but only get the default blue Z (+)-(+) handle. Everywhere I've looked there is this selection window in the top left to select the desired axis and I've tried a number of different guesses / approaches -nothing.
If anyone can help, thanks in advance!
PS: I'm new, and not aware of how to post pics / video of my problem.
Ken.

Comment: Hi. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the tutorial you saw was created on a beta version of 2.80 before around March this year. Later betas and the release version (2.80.75) moved those settings to the right-hand properties sidebar. Press the N key then the vertical 'Tools' tab on the edge of the window to show the settings indicated in the image below.
[image: Spin tool settings]

Comment: Wow, that's really annoying - why not just make them all visible? The axis chosen to be visible isn't even the logical first choice given the face's orientation. Took me a shocking amount of time to find what should have been intuitive - typical Blender nonsense.